# Rails: Can't send a div's html to its controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

When I press a button in a view, I need to grab the html of a div on the page and send it to my controller in Rails but I can't figure out how to do it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? I can't see any good reason in sending piece of markup generated by application back to application.

Comment: I was trying to pass the html within a div back to the server to have it converted to a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty easy with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#mybutton').click(function () {
    var html = $('#mydiv').html();
    $.post('/path/to/controller', {div_html : html});
  });
});
```

The div HTML will be accessible in your action under `params[:div_html]`.

Comment: Thanks. The requirements of my app ended up changing and I didn't up needing to do this but this looks like it would be a solution. Thanks!